# Converting index of string to integers

Tags: java, string, char, int

I'm attempting to convert the characters at a specific String index to an integer.

This is the function I have:

```
public int[] digitsOfPi(int n) {
    {            
        String piDigits = Double.toString(Math.PI);
        int[] piArray = new int[n];           
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            piArray[i] = Character.digit(piDigits.charAt(i), n);;
        }
        return piArray;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I test this function with `digitsOfPi(3)`, I got

```
[I@15db9742
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you use for outputting its result?

Comment: System.out.println(digitsOfPi(3));

Comment: You are printing the array object id, loop over the array to print it's elements

Comment: Is the actual function working properly and not printing correct, or is the function itself incorrect?

Comment: Looks like the printing is not correct, guessing by the name of the function you want to get 3 digits of pi, so the printing is incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Use `Arrays.toString(arg)`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digitsOfPi(3)));
```

... to get pretty result output like
`[1, 2, 3]`

What you have printed is a reference to the array, not its content. That is why I asked first about the way youre outputting the result.

---

Thi signature of `Character.digit()` is `(char ch, int RADIX)`. So you use ternary number system or how to call it. Moreover, it returns -1 when the `char ch` does not contain valid number, it is your case `3.1415...` is `[invalid, invalid, 1]`. You need to use 10 as an argument and skip 2nd position.
Or you can simply do

```
piArray[i] = piDigits.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Comment: Thats what youve got in the array. Wait, I will look at the function itself

Comment: Ok, works a little better. Unfortunately now I get [3, -2, 1], where -2 represents the '.' (decimal place). Any way to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `System.out.pritln(digitsOfPi(3)` for getting the element at 3rd position, but actually its returning an array of `int`

So try to use the following code snippet, instead -

```
    public static int digitsOfPi(int n) {
       String piDigits = Double.toString(Math.PI);
       char[] array = piDigits.toCharArray();
       return Character.getNumericValue(array[3]);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically need this method to return an array of int.

Comment: @statsguyz now you can get an int from it